# PHP mailer adding CSS

Tags: php, forms

I got my PHP mail form working great and just have one last touch I wanted to add. Basically I am pulling the info from the form like this:

```
$fields{"Comments"} = "Additional Comments by Fitter:  ";
```

The HTML for this field is:

```
<textarea name="Comments" id="styled" onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="setbg('white')">Enter your comment here...</textarea>
```

The email would then displays:

> Additional Comments by Fitter:  Enter your comment here...

I would like the info being pulled to be a different color. I have tried:

```
$fields{"<span style='color:red;'>Comments</span>"} = "Additional Comments by Fitter:  ";
```

but then no comments are displayed (I assume I am not wrapping it right). I have:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

At the top of the file as well. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the value, not the key.

Comment: I bring in all the values to the body through this
`$body = "We have received the following:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){  $body .= sprintf("%2s %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }`

Not sure how to just wrap the Value.